# There is no ip in structure thread_struct in x86_64, so how can the kernel switch to the correct ip in new process?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

There is no ip in structure thread_struct in x86_64, so how can the function context_switch switch to the correct ip of the new process?

Answer (score 0):

I think the core registers(special registers and general registers) are saved in the kernel stack of the process which is interrupted. Each time interrupt/exception happens, the CPU trap to supervisor mode(privilege mode), kernel will save the context(one stack frame) to kernel stack of the process which has been interrupted.

I think the sp(stack pointer) register should be saved in the thread_struct, which point to the top of the kernel stack for the specific process, context_switch will use the sp to recover the context for the process ready to be run.